# scala mixin and single initialization

Tags: scala, inheritance, mixins, traits

I want to use Metrics as a mixin.

So, I want to define multiple classes like this (pseudo-code):

```
class MyClass1 extends MyParent with MyMetricsHelper(myJMXMBeanServer)
class MyClass2 extends MyParent with MyMetricsHelper(myJMXMBeanServer) // repeat parameter bad
class MyClass3 extends MyParent with MyMetricsHelper(myJMXMBeanServer) // repeat parameter bad
```

as you see, when I call `MyMetricsHelper`, I pass in the parameters for `myJMXMBeanServer` so it would know to log to it.

However, I don't want to repeat `myJMXMBeanServer` in every class which mixes it in, because it's not nice to duplicate it.

Also, I do not want to have a different single point which will initialize the `MyMetricsHelper` because It does not look beautiful to me because I just want to mix it in and for it to work, I don't want to remember I have another point in code where I have to initialize it.

Any elegant way to achieve that?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Traits [are not allowed to have constructor parameters](http://www.artima.com/pins1ed/traits.html#12.1).

Instead, you could define a sub-trait that specified `myJMXBeanServer` for you (I'm not quite sure why you think initialization in one single place is bad --- it's either that or initialization in several places, which is what you have now):

```
class MyParent

trait MyMetricsHelper {
  val server: AnyRef // Replace by actual type, this means
                     // that we expect any impl. to initialize this field somehow
}

trait MyJMXMetricsHelper extends MyMetricsHelper {
  val server = "myJMXMBeanServer"
}

class MyClass1 extends MyParent with MyJMXMetricsHelper
class MyClass2 extends MyParent with MyJMXMetricsHelper
class MyClass3 extends MyParent with MyJMXMetricsHelper
```